# Apache nutch and anti-spam databases

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Using Nutch to collect urls from websites and noticed that after running it for  about a day my ip address gets black-listed by some major websites that I haven't crawled at all. After further instigation seems that, somehow, my IP address, gets listed on anti-spam databases which could explain why.

Considering that I'm already following the default configurations and politeness rules I'm wondering if anyone knows how to prevent this? How do Google and other major search engines work around this? Do I have to have a large pool of IP addresses?

Comment: Are you respecting [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) and politely sending a unique, useful user agent string? I suspect the major players run honeypots to catch bots that don't play by the rules.

Comment: Yes I do respect robots.txt and have a useful agent string.

Comment: Unfortunately even if you follow all the rules you may hit a honeypots and it will mark your IP as a bot/crawler. Normally people don't block Google/Bing/etc. because they want to be found on the different search engines. But can it be challenging for small crawlers.